# How to see all udev events during boot?

Tags: systemd, udev

Need to see the udev events to write rules.

I've tried to set `udev_log="debug"` in `/etc/udev/udev.conf`.

I've tried to edit `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-top/udev` to set `log_level=debug` there. Also the `--debug` option:

```
...
log_level=debug
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=$log_level /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon --debug --resolve-names=never 2>/dev/.udev.debug
...
```

And rebuilt initramfs every time:

```
update-initramfs -k all -u
```

After a reboot nothing is logged to the file, `journalctl -u systemd-udevd` doesn't show events.

I'm currently using an additional service to see the events:

```
[Unit]
Description=udev Monitoring
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=systemd-udevd.service
After=systemd-udevd-control.socket systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
Before=sysinit.target systemd-udev-trigger.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/sbin/udevadm monitor --udev --env > /dev/udev_monitor.log"

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using Ubuntu 18.04 in a VirtualBox.

1. In Grub menu, press <kbd>E</kbd> for edit. Remove `quiet splash` to get boot in text mode.
2. Add `udev.log-priority=debug`. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

You can see the udev messages while booting or after using:

```
journalctl -u systemd-udevd
```

For permanent settings, you may set `udev.log-priority=debug` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`

**Source:**
- [archlinux - Udev debug output](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Debug_output)

Comment: Kinda works for me, however at the end of boot the server just gets restarted. No restart happens in absence of the option.

Comment: Upgrade of a kernel helped with the reboot, but now the debug entries are gone as well. The option doesn't do anything. What an odd option.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this and you need to set SYSTEMD_LOG_TARGET=console as well when redirecting udevd's stderr. I thought I was going mad!