# removing device from device list linux

Tags: devices

i am working on a project and after some time i stumble upon the next error:

```
Unable to get name for joystick /dev/input/js0
Failed to get vendor ID of joystick /dev/input/js0
Failed to get product ID of joystick /dev/input/js0
Unable to get name for joystick /dev/input/js1
Failed to get vendor ID of joystick /dev/input/js1
Failed to get product ID of joystick /dev/input/js1
Unable to get name for joystick /dev/input/js2
Failed to get vendor ID of joystick /dev/input/js2
Failed to get product ID of joystick /dev/input/js2
Unable to get name for joystick /dev/input/js3
Failed to get vendor ID of joystick /dev/input/js3
Failed to get product ID of joystick /dev/input/js3
```

(its from SFML, but its not that important)

and i want to remove the devices js0-3 but don't know how, i found the devices file in /proc/bus/input and i found this:

```
...

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input26
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 js0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1b

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event16 js1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1b

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event17 js2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1b

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=045e Product=0719 Version=0100
N: Name="Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input29
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event18 js3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=f 0 0 0 0 0 0 7fdb000000000000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1b

...
```

and can't edit it because its rom, so what should i do?

please help me

i tried deleting the js0-3 files from /dev/input and that didn't solve the problem (and now i lack the original files, so i made some empty files names js0-3) so i then tried to edit the /proc/bus/input/devices file but didn't succed

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Did you try unloading the module that creates those files? From the info you posted I'd assume it is a `xpad`, so `sudo rmmod xpad`. If `xpad` isn't the one, you can try gather more information with a `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/input/js0`

Comment: ```rmmod: ERROR: Module xpad is not currently loaded```
and after i tried to get info i got this: ```Unknown device "/dev/input/js0": Inappropriate ioctl for device```

Comment: Hmm, odd. Anyway, I presume these files creates something development-related you're doing, right? I'd suggest reboot the system, check that the files are absent, then use `lsmod > /tmp/1`, then do some stuff that creates these files, then `lsmod > /tmp/2`, then compare the difference before and after, e.g. with `vimdiff /tmp/{1,2}`. I'd expect you'll see a new module appears in the list of loaded modules, which creates these files.

Comment: the thing is that i once used a wireless controller and now i want to completly remove it from the system

Comment: I see. Are you sure the wireless controller doesn't get connected while the system is running? Is it disabled? I'm asking because files under `/dev` are generated automatically in runtime, they don't exist on disk. So these `jsX` files you are seeing are getting generated due to some event happening. Did you connect the joystick over bluetooth? If yes, did you try removing the joystick from the list of saved bluetootch connections? Do you see anything interesting in `journalctl -b | grep -i joystick`?

Comment: i dont have the joystick connected since like 1 month ago, no, nothing interesting after running journalclt. Also i removed the joystick from bluethooth and nothing changed

Comment: In this case I think you'll have to use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227170/266507) to increase verbosity of udev on boot, and then grep through the log for `js` and `joystick` keywords trying to find which events lead to creation of these files. Be aware this will generate a lot of output.